# Design approach for kafka consumer application

Tags: .net, postgresql, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

Trying to analyze/narrow down design approach.
Requirement is to listen/subscribe Kafka messages and then, process/updates messages and
store into Postgresql database.

We have EC2 instance - windows server and trying to see what should we use to create kafka consumer which can listen and process messages.

Considering to create *.Net windows service/worker service* as kafka consumer & process/store messages to postgresql.

Or
Can you advise which other better design option to use along with EC2 instance ?

As this is EC2 instance , not sure if Lambda will be helpful OR should create stand alone application (preferred .Net tech stack) service.

Comment: Based on the limited info you've provided, this appears to be a fairly clear-cut use-case for running the JDBC sink connector. See https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/

Comment: Just adding some info, its windows EC2 cloud server.   Is there better option if using .NET CORE Service OR , Lambda will be the better approach here ? So,   <Kafka Listener Application as self managed Service OR Lambda> => process messages => store to postgres.

Comment: Your "Kafka Listener Application" should be a JDBC connector. Lambda isn't appropriate.

Comment: Lambda has little to do with EC2. Unclear how you'd be creating any lambda triggers, and if you already had code running in EC2, you'd just trigger a function there unless that needs to be more scalable... BTW, If Kafka is running in MSK, you can use MSK Connect

Comment: So JDBC connector needs to use on consumer application.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ok. So As code will be running on EC2 then its no much sense to create Lamda function. When there is no EC2 instance then, Is it better option to go with Lamda ?

Comment: Really depends on scalability. One EC2 instance can only run so many threads, and therefore only consume/process so many events. If you really need to scale out, then spinning up a fleet of EC2 instances is generally more expensive than Lambda events, however, you still need to invoke some webhook/HTTP call to trigger the lambda; I don't think lambda can read events from any random Kafka cluster

Comment: **However**, Kafka Connect (recommended here, not C#) is its own process, and needs to be run on a cluster of EC2 (or ECS/EKS) instances